# How to implement OperationQueue with audioFileUrls - Swift - Xcode 11 beta 5

Tags: swift, xcode, nsoperationqueue

I am trying to implement NSOperationQueue in order to be able to cancel a process which merges audio files (using (audioFileUrls: NSArray) method) but I don't know how to implement it, I am getting confused by the different exemples accessibles. Could someone add the missing code in the exemple I am providing here? Thanks.

```
Import Cocoa
Import AVFoundation

let queue = OperationQueue.main

@IBAction func build(_ sender: NSButton){
   builder()
}

@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: NSButton){
   queue.cancelAllOperations()
}

func builder() {
   queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1                   
   queue.addOperation {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own queue

```
lazy var myOperationQueue: OperationQueue = {
    var queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.name = "Image merge queue"
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    return queue
  }()
```

and then use it in the `builder()`

```
func builder() {
   myOperationQueue.addOperation {...}
}
```

Also keep in mind that cancel does not cancel operation that are currently in execution [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1417849-cancelalloperations)

> Canceling the operations does not automatically remove them from the queue or stop those that are currently executing.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The queue is well created ('myOperationQueue.name' : com.apple.main-thread) and active ('myOperationQueue.isSuspended' = false), the process goes on, and after using 'myOperationQueue.cancelAllOperations()', it keeps on running until the end. In my opinion not because the process is still alive but because the status of the queue still the same ('myOperationQueue.isSuspended' = false (even after running 'myOperationQueue.cancelAllOperations()' )). This is weird

Comment: `You should create your own queue` and don't use the main queue, you should not `cancelAllOperations()` the MAIN queue it will block the UI and none of the operations will be blocked.